# How to sync Terraform state with my AWS infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation

#### Error during terraform apply and terraform state has no idea about rest of the resources it created

I was creating some resources my AWS account using Terraform. My terraform project contains over 45 resources out of which one of them is AWS CloudFormation stack. My terraform state is managed with GitLab APIs over `http` configuration.
When I ran my script, `gitlab-terraform apply` the Terraform was able to create most of the resources mentioned in the script (44 out of 45) but it failed to create AWS:CloudFormation stack resource (due to [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74758906/aws-how-to-fix-resource-limit-error-while-creating-aws-waf-resources)).

Now, after this incident gitlab-terraform state has no recollection of the 44 resources it created. State file contains only details about 4 resources and next time when I run commands like `gitlab-terraform plan` and `gitlab-terraform apply` it is showing me a plan to create 41 resources and on `apply` it fails saying resources exist with same name.

Is there a way to fix this out of sync between Terraform state and my AWS infrastructure?

#### I have already tried

`terraform refresh` command with plan and with apply but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Delete the resources from AWS or import them into terraform, both are manual operations.

Comment: @luk2302 its kind of irritating to delete 41 resources manually

Comment: Yes, does not change anything about the two options though.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra no no I have 1000s of resources in my AWS account

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you will either need to import all the resources or delete them manually, there isn't a way to automatically import existing resources to update the state file.

Now, to avoid this problem from happening again in the future, save your terraform state file in S3 and control the state lock using dynamodb.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket          = "terraform-bucket"
    key             = "terraform.tfstate"
    region          = "eu-west-1"
    profile         = "my-profile"
    dynamodb_table  = "terraform-locks"
    encrypt         = true
  }
}
```