# AWS: How to fix Resource limit error while creating AWS WAF resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

Ran into `AWS WAF cloudn't perform the operation because you exceeded your resource limit` error while creating following resources:

- 10X `AWS::WAFv2::IPSet`
- Maybe AWS::WebACL (CloudFormation did not try to create this)

What is the exact reason of this happening?
What type of quotas I need to upgrade?

Comment: have you checked this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/waf-limit-exceeded-error/

Comment: @JatinMehrotra no that is not helpful, I am getting resource limit on IPSet